# Adding new points of interest to Here.com API results

Tags: geocoding, here-api, point-of-sale, point-of-interest

A client of mine wants to implement some sort of store locator on his website. But he wants this store locator to be able to give results in a radius of 20km around the search query provided by the user.

I'm actually combining both our own database (for exact match) with Here API (for geocoding and discovering points of interest based on a specific query in this 20km radius). This works fine.
The thing is, one of my client's store doesn't show up in Here list of points of interest.

Since I saw that Here was also using Help and TripAdvisor API to get points of interest, I tried to create this business in TripAdvisor. The business has been accepted / created in TripAdvisor, but it still doesn't show up in Here API results.

Does someone know how we can add public points of interest in Here and make them show up in API results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition of new POI(points of interest) which will also get reflected in the API, as per the customer request can be raised via following portal.

https://mapcreator.here.com/